# Error : "SDL could not initialize! SDL_Error: dsp: No such audio device"

Tags: c++, sdl, sdl-mixer

I'm currently working on a personnal project and I have an issue with SDL_mixer or Audio

I can compile without any problems but when I try to execute the program I got this error:

"SDL could not initialize! SDL_Error: dsp: No such audio device"

[image: screenshot of terminal]

I'm compiling with cmake, this is my CMakeList.txt :

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0)

set(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE Debug)
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++14")
set(CMAKE_MODULE_PATH ${CMAKE_MODULE_PATH} "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/cmake/")

project(R-TYPE)

find_package(SDL2 REQUIRED)
find_package(SDL2_image REQUIRED)
find_package(SDL2_ttf REQUIRED)
find_package(SDL2_mixer REQUIRED)

include_directories(${SDL2_INCLUDE_DIRS} ${SDL2_IMAGE_INCLUDE_DIRS} ${SDL2_TTF_INCLUDE_DIRS} ${SDL2_MIXER_INCLUDE_DIRS})

add_executable(
    R-TYPE
    main.cpp
    Render/renderWindow.cpp
    Menu/menu.cpp
)
target_link_libraries(R-TYPE ${SDL2_LIBRARIES} ${SDL2_IMAGE_LIBRARIES} ${SDL2_TTF_LIBRARIES} ${SDL2_MIXER_LIBRARIES})
```

this is the function where I got the error from :

```cpp
int main(int argc, char* args[])
{
    if (SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING) < 0) 
    {
        std::cout << "SDL could not initialize! SDL_Error: " << SDL_GetError() << std::endl;
        return 84;
    }
    RenderWindow window("R-TYPE", 1920, 1080);

    while (gameRunning)
    {
        game(window);
    }
    window.cleanUp();
    SDL_Quit();
    TTF_Quit();
    return 0;
}
```

I'm on UBUNTU, how can I fix this?

I already tried to install libasound2-dev libpulse-dev but that didn't work

Comment: Did you by any chance compile SDL yourself?

Comment: What does that mean ? I build the SDL library once but I don't even know if my cmakelist.txt is taking the library that I build or not

Comment: I compile with the cmakelist btw, idk if its an answer to your question

Comment: *"I build the SDL library once"* Yes, that's what I was asking. Perhaps you didn't do it correctly? E.g. failed to install the required dependencies? This can produce a not-fully-functioning SDL. Remove it and install from `apt` instead.

Comment: I did that command : sudo apt-get install libsdl2-dev
tells me that this lib is already installed with the highest version of it

Comment: What about SDL2_mixer?

Comment: If you installed self-built SDL to /usr/local, you must also purge it from there.

Comment: Yeah I think I missbuild the fcking library and now its broking the whole thing....
How can I purge SDL from /usr/local/ ?

Comment: and I already have the last version of SDL2_mixer

Comment: Not sure what would be a good way. `/usr/local` contains only empty directories by default, so you can delete the whole directory. Or look at the contents and search for SDL2 (look in `/usr/local/include` and `/usr/local/lib`, perhaps `/usr/local/bin` too).

Comment: ok nice I did it, I deleted /usr/local/include/SDL2. What I have to do now ?

Comment: Delete stuff from `/usr/local/lib` too. There are probably `libSDL2....` in here. Then everything should just work.

Comment: Do I delete all the libSDL2 files ? there is a lot

Comment: Ok I did it, now what do I do ? I recompile my project ?

Comment: Yes, all of them. Use `find /usr/local -iname '*sdl*'` to search for the files. Yes, then rebuilding your project should work.

Comment: ok but now my CMakeList.txt is not working anymore... he can't find SDL2_INCLUDE_DIR

Comment: You probably missed something in `/usr/local`.

Comment: it work, love u genius

Answer (score 2):

This is caused by manually building SDL2 and/or SDL2_mixer (without having all required dependencies installed).

Installing them from `apt` instead fixes the issue. The self-built versions had to be purged from `/usr/local`.

Comment: how? apt install ?

Comment: @BerylAmend Yes, `sudo apt install libsdl2-dev`.

Comment: thanks ,but im using colab and it didnt work do u know what should i do to solve the error: ALSA: Couldn't open audio device: No such file or directory

Comment: @BerylAmend You should post a new question about it, and include all the details.

Comment: yes i did but they closed it!

Comment: @BerylAmend Then you need to get it reopened (or repost it in an improved form to prevent closure). If you don't understand how to improve the question, ask how to improve it on https://meta.stackoverflow.com/